# Why isn't my C++ program working?

Tags: c++, string, definitions

No idea why this isn't working, everything seems to be right but maybe I'm missing something obvious as I'm just getting to know C++.

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string ask(){
    string ans2;
    cout << "Type:";
    cin >> ans2;
    return ans2;

}

int main()
{
    string ans2;
    string ans1="Hello";
    ask();
    cout << ans1 << " turns into " << ans2;
    return 0;
}
```

With the error message of:

```
Line 20:[Error] no match for call to '(std::string {aka     std::basic_string<char>}) (std::string&)'

Line 6:[Error] 'ans2' was not declared in this scope
Line 6:[Error] expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
```

Comment: You probably wanted `ans2 = ask();`, but other than that this code compiles fine for me.

Comment: The program you have problem with isn't the same as you show here. To begin with, line 20 is the closing `}` of the `main` function in this program.

Comment: I just compiled using C++14 and it seems to compile. http://ideone.com/sUgMSU

Comment: compiles in gcc 4.8 also at c++98 standard

Comment: @norritt I **know** that this question would be completely off-topic on Code Review. Please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Simon Forsberg Thanks for the link I actually didn't know that Code Review even required the code to work. I thought of a plattform to discuss more subjective matters which don't belong on SO according to the FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ans2` in `main` and in `ask` are two different variables. When you return the value of `ans2` in your `ask` function, you need to capture it in your `main` function via `ans2 = ask();`. [Working example on ideone](http://ideone.com/h4IuWu)